# Change Paragraph Element by clicking on button with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a site to change a users current password. Under the form i have an empty paragraph element, which I want to fill with text like "Your current password is wrong!".

```js
document.getElementById("erroroutput").innerHTML = 'Your current password is wrong'
```

```html
<p id="erroroutput" style="color:rgb(254,54,42);margin-top:20px;text-align:center;">Beispieltext</p>
```

I tried the same output with an alert and it worked, but it wont change the paragraph.

Comment: Seems to work for me  https://jsfiddle.net/u84bL5rh/

Comment: The code provided would be run from top to bottom. Is the script lower in the page than the <p>? If not, the p tag would not have been created yet when the script runs

Comment: I edited your question and pasted your code in a stack snippet and it appears to work fine. Have you checked your actual code for errors in the console?

Comment: Yeah thank's @Zeph that was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed the following code 
document.getElementById("erroroutput").innerHTML = 'Your current password is wrong' in script tag as shown below and you can also see the image of the code by clicking on "enter image description here" link

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>

<button type="button"
onclick="abc()">
Click me</button>

<p id="erroroutput" style="color:rgb(254,54,42);margin-top:20px;text-align:center;">Beispieltext</p>
<script>
function abc(){
document.getElementById("erroroutput").innerHTML = 'Your current password is wrong'}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rFl5.png)